# Designing an adjustable count-down timer

Tags: digital-logic

I am trying to design a digital timer that receives a time, t, as input and after t seconds it triggers a buzzer. It is actually similar to a kitchen timer but we can adjust the time ourself.

A way to do this is using a "555 IC" but the time will be a function of the resistor and the capacitor we choose and we don't have control over the time after we build the circuit.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: Use a micro....

Comment: How does it receive "a time, t, as input" exactly?

Comment: *we don't have control over the time after we build the circuit* **Not true** if you replace the resistor with a **variable** resistor or make it switchable to choose between different resistor and/or capacitor combinations. You **must** specify how much count down time you want, a 555 gets "troublesome" if you want more than a minute or so.

Answer (score 2):

Use a (simple) microcontroller. You can add electronics or whatever component to receive the time it is even easy to add a WIFI/RF type to make it wireless or you can use SPI, I2C, serial/uart/USB etc when using a microcontroller).

Store the time in a variable, and control the buzzer directly via the microcontroller after a simple comparison of elapsed time and current time.

Probably receiving the time will be most hard to do without a microcontroller, assuming a (decent) protocol is needed.

(btw, it is possible to make a variable resistor, but it is a bit of a 'dirty solution' if not using a programmable resistor: use a LED, let it glow for some percentage. Attach a photo diode to it and put tape around the LED and photo diode. The amount of light of the LED will result in a difference resistance of the photo diode. I don't know if there is also some trick for capacitors).

Comment: Ha! Never saw that kind of variable resistor! Notice that it's still a diode, so it must be biased to some forward voltage to exhibit a (somewhat) linear current/voltage behaviour. You could of course just use the voltage (or current) you use to control the LED brightness to set the bias point of a non-photo diode, and get a similar behaviour. If you, instead of having a positive bias voltage, have a negative one (i.e. you flip the diode around), the diode is in reverse direction, and will act like a capacitor! There's diodes that are optimized for this usage, called Varicaps (PIN diodes).

Comment: (cool idea, by the way, using brightness of an LED to control the effective resistance of a photodiode; I like that idea. Basically, you get isolation for free – maybe one could just abuse an optocoupler for that)

Comment: Thanks ... and yes, but with a microcontroller it must be not so difficult to make a formula from the amout of brightness (taking the forward voltage into account) and the requested amount of resistance. Actually it can more than a default variable resistor and let the work be done by the microcontroller.

Comment: And cool idea to use the same idea as a capacitor ...I'm really a beginner with electronics, never new a variable capacitor could be made with simple parts.

Comment: The varicap diode is very commonly used in radio electronics, when, for some reasons, you need to have an adjustable filter, or a widely adjustable oscillator.

Comment: Maybe I should ' play'  with it a time, I don't own them (having just some basic items to use).

Comment: You can probably actually do the same with a very "boring" standard rectifier diode! The higher the reverse voltage, the wider the isolating zone in between the P- and the N-region in the diode; that translates to a larger capacitor plate distance, which means sinking capacitance with increasing \$\left\lvert V_\text{reverse}\right\rvert\$. But: normal diodes have a capacitance of a few pF, so not very much and not very easy to make use of. See for example this [1N4001 datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds28002.pdf), page 2, figure bottom right.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation and explanation (although it's above above my knowledge). I have several types of default diodes, and I'm almost sure 1N4001 is one of them.